# MySQL Altering a Trigger to use a dynamic database name

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, prepared-statement

I have a perfectly working trigger.  As I'm adding in more tests I'm finding that I want to alter this trigger to dynamically select the database based on the current database.  In production this trigger resided in database `rdata` and talks to `default`.   However in testing the trigger resides in `test_rdata` and talks to `test_default`.  How can I modify the below trigger to dynamically select the right database

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `af_rdata_data_trigger_4` $$
CREATE TRIGGER af_rdata_data_trigger_4
    AFTER INSERT on Results FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE project_id INT;
        -- Do this first - another table may have already created it..
        INSERT INTO default.rdata_project (`user`,`result_number`, `created_on`)
        VALUES (USER(), NEW.LBLDGRUNNO, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_update=NOW();
        -- Now push in our values 

        -- THIS IS WHAT NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC!!
        UPDATE default.rdata_project project JOIN Results
        ON project.result_number = Results.LBLDGRUNNO SET
            project.annual_total_cost = Results.FTOTCOST
        WHERE project.result_number=NEW.LBLDGRUNNO;

    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic **SELECT** statement using **STORED PROCEDURE** and **CALL** that procedure from your **TRIGGER**. Check below code for example:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_UpdateProject`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_UpdateProject`(IN _dbName VARCHAR(100), IN _LBLDGRUNNO INT)
BEGIN 
    SET @s = CONCAT("UPDATE ", _dbName, ".rdata_project project ");
    SET @s = CONCAT(@s, "JOIN Results ON project.result_number = Results.LBLDGRUNNO ");
    SET @s = CONCAT(@s, "SET project.annual_total_cost = Results.FTOTCOST ");
    SET @s = CONCAT(@s, "WHERE project.result_number=", _LBLDGRUNNO,";");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `af_rdata_data_trigger_4` $$
CREATE TRIGGER af_rdata_data_trigger_4
    AFTER INSERT ON Results FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE project_id INT;
        -- Do this first - another table may have already created it..
        INSERT INTO default.rdata_project (`user`,`result_number`, `created_on`)
        VALUES (USER(), NEW.LBLDGRUNNO, NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE last_update=NOW();
        -- Now push in our values 

        -- THIS IS WHAT NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC!!
        CALL sp_UpdateProject(dbName, NEW.LBLDGRUNNO);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There HAS to be a simpler way.  Really is that it?  Oh no...  Thanks!

Comment: You can't use prepare statement in trigger so you have to create stored procedure to generate dynamic query

Comment: Where is dbName set?  And then where does that get changed out?

Comment: You have to pass the dbname in which you want to update the record when you call procedure. It depends on you what you want to pass in argument

Comment: What if we go another route.  How can I determine the database the trigger is running on.  Then can't I do this?  `IF <current_db> REGEXP '^test_' THEN <repl_db> = test_<repl_db>`

Comment: That thing can be easily done in trigger and take this dbname in paremeter and pass it in argument and you can also do this in procedure

Comment: @SaharshShah: I am also facing same issue but your solution is not correct as you are calling stored procedure from trigger and trigger will not allow prepare statement even in stored procedure...please execute your code it will give error like "Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger"